# Is the the output of Q' in an S-R Latch used for anything, or is only the Q output important?

Tags: circuit-design, memory, boolean-algebra, latch

From looking at a diagram like this:

[image]

and watching some videos on the topic, it seems that Q represents a 1-bit memory, but I'm unsure if there is a purpose for Q'.

Comment: What if I need the inverted value of Q to implement a combinational logic after the latch? Say, F = Q'.P

Comment: @MituRaj Nah. Just rename R as S and S as R and then Q becomes /Q. (Unless you need both outputs.)

Comment: Of course one may need two outputs at a time, and an unnecessary NOT gate can be avoided in that situation. @jonk

Comment: @MituRaj Of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qbar is used internally, as part of the latch, so it has to be there.

So the real question becomes, do we want Qbar to be available as an output pin?

It depends on whether you want it. If at some point in decoding you'll want the inverse of Q as well as Q, then it saves an inverter - and the time taken for the signal to go through an inverter.

Let's look at two different parts for two different purposes.

A 74HC74 is intended to be a very general purpose flip-flop, with set and reset inputs as well as Q and Qbar outputs, and two independent latches fit nicely into a 16 pin package.

A 74HC174 is six latches in the same size 16 pin package, and features only Q outputs and a common clock and master reset.

Decide whether you want Qbar outputs, and then find packages that optimise the rest of your design.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense